# How to document a system

Tags: systems-engineering

I have built three system on digital dentistry and I plan to document them in academic format: Overall system, data flow and process in it.

Do we have standard, common format, template or so?

Comment: There are multiple common formats, including various process flow charts or block diagrams, tables of interface definitions (often in control documents), and many others that relate to specific subsystems (electrical, plumbing, structural, thermal, etc). Formats often differ by intent- documentation for users vs maintainers and installers vs engineering other systems to interface with vs manufacturing